# What is a weather system?

Tags: meteorology, climate, planetary-science

I heard on Star Talk Radio that Jupiter has weather systems larger than Earth so I was just curious to know what the definition of a weather system is exactly.

Comment: In this context they are likely talking about an anti-cyclonic pressure system that creates a character spiral formation (induced by the Coriolis effect).  Systems like that on Jupiter (e.g. the Great Red Spot) can get wider than our Earth.  All the gaseous giants have very large systems because the planets themselves are so large.